# iOS: Using custom UITableViewCell vs. Using Cell viewWithTag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

**Custom Cell For UITableViewCell**

I'm developing an `iOS` application and i need to make a custom `cell` for my side menu, i have seen so many examples and i found out those two approaches :

1. Make a class (.h and .m files) that inherits from `UITableViewCell` and put the `outlets` in the .h file then apply the class on the cell and  connect those outlets to the labels and/or images from your cell in the storyboard.
2. Or the easy way is to give a `tag` to the labels/images or whatever you have in the cell in your storyboard.

**My Question**: I'm wondering which way is more accurate and professional and used by most iOS developers ?

Comment: Recommended way of doing this is by Subclassing UItableViewCell because viewWithTag is a costly method..!!

Comment: Do professional programmers use the quick-and-dirty way, or the de-facto standard subclassing proven by years of object-oriented programming?

Comment: @Cyrille i'm new to `iOS` world, that's why i'm asking :)

Comment: My comment is still valid for every language, every framework, every platform you'll ever encounter.

Comment: What do you mean by "professional"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely the first one. It's clear and maintainable in the future. The purpose of the tag is not to store arbitrary values. See my [answer regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722113/how-to-access-index-path-of-button-in-a-custom-tableviewcell/29722197#29722197).

[This article has some details on the usage of tags](http://benford.me/blog/12-dos-and-donts-for-ios-development/)

Comment: By former, you mean the first approach ?

Comment: Thanks for that second useful link !